# HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/... returned "Invalid Upload Request"

Tags: python, google-drive-api

Not sure what is going on under the API here, but from my debug output, everything looks okay.  It is passing an ID to a valid file and so forth.  Is there any way to enable debug output in the Google SDK?

I see a couple of warnings before the HTTP error:

```
WARNING:oauth2client.util:new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)
WARNING:oauth2client.util:new_request() takes at most 1 positional argument (2 given)
```

Here is the code:

```
def update(self, path, properties, media_body = None):
    info = self.stat(path)

    if not info:
        debug("No such file: %s" % path)
        return None

    # Merge properties
    for k, v in properties.iteritems():
        # Do not update the ID, always use the path obtained ID.
        if k == 'id': continue

        setattr(info, k, v)

    try:
        debug("Updating: %s" % info)
        return self.service().files().update(
            fileId = info.id,
            body = info.dict(),
            media_body = media_body
        ).execute()
    except Exception, e:
        debug("Update failed: %s" % str(e))
        debug.stack()
        return None
```

Okay, this function is called via a file class (either local or remote).  In this case, it is the remote file class calling this function, providing a reference to the local file class uploader (media_upload):

So in the remote file class, I have implemented this method.  The Drive() class is my own wrapper for the Google API:

```
def _updateFile(self, path, src):
    debug("Updating remote file: %s" % path)

    if GsyncOptions.dry_run: return

    drive = Drive()
    info = drive.update(path, src.getInfo(), src.getUploader())

    if info is None:
        debug("Update failed")
```

The 'src' variable is a reference to another file class (the local file).  It calls getUploader to pass a reference to the uploader.  This is implemented as follows:

```
def getUploader(self, path = None):
    info = self.getInfo(path)
    if info is None:
        raise Exception("Could not obtain file information: %s" % path)

    path = self.getPath(path)

    f = open(path, "r")
    if f is None:
        raise Exception("Open failed: %s" % path)

    from apiclient.http import MediaIOBaseUpload

    return MediaIoBaseUpload(f, info.mimeType, resumable=True)
```

Comment: Please share the code where you build `media_body`. Also, does this same error occur when you don't pass `media_body` parameter and only update metadata?

Comment: I'll try without media_body.  If you give me a moment, I will post the media_body code...

Comment: I removed the media_body and as you may have suspected, the update seemed to work.  However, the intention is to update the file content.

Comment: Oh, and the warnings have gone too.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the "Is there any way to enable debug output in the Google SDK?" part of the question, check out https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/logging.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll enable this, see if I can see what is happening.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: whilst I agree with the principle, in this case the link I posted is the definitive reference from Google themselves on how to enable debugging within the python SDK. Rather than copy.paste parts of the page, which could quickly become out-of-date as Google updates its libraries, by passing the link, future readers will be directed to the up to date, definitive reference.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seemed to be that the `insert()` API method for creating a document, requires a defined value for the document body (or media_body).  I initially created the document empty, providing no document body at all, essentially leaving it as `None`.  This created the scenario where I had a document on the Drive that I couldn't update.  By creating the document with an empty body, the updates then started working:

```
return self.service().files().insert(
    body = info.dict(),
    # An empty media_body.
    media_body = ""
).execute()
```